# Shift a position (latitude, longitude) by adding a vector

Tags: vectors, coordinate-systems

Let us assume we have some position given in latitude and longitude decimal degrees. Now, we want to move this position by adding some vector given with some magnitude (length) and phase (direction).

Is it now correct to just convert the polar coordinates of the vector into Cartesian (x,y) coordinates and then to add the x,y to the latitude/longitude? Or is it not that simple since the geographic position is mapped to a 3D sphere (earth) and not a 2D plane?

And if it is not that simple, how would one do it correctly?

Comment: It is not that simple,  but for small magnitudes it is a good approximation. The position, origin & direction defines a two dimensional plane, you can work out the angle required to travel the given distance along the circumference and then compute the position of the resulting point.

Comment: It’s a simple exercise in spherical trigonometry, but I don’t see that your method could work.